PlateJS : "Could not resolve dependency" when installing a new component
I use PlateJS on React
I wanted to install a new component, so I installed it with the same command used to install the other components (@udecode/plate-ui@latest add [platejs component name)
I wanted the image element component, so I did npx @udecode/plate-ui@latest add image-element
But it didn't work as usual, I got this error:
see image here
npx @udecode/plate-ui@latest add image-element

⠸ Installing image-element...Command failed with exit code 1: npm install @udecode/plate-media

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! While resolving: portfolio-react@0.0.0

npm ERR! Found: @udecode/plate-common@30.4.5

npm ERR! node_modules/@udecode/plate-common

npm ERR!   @udecode/plate-common@"^30.4.5" from the root project

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer @udecode/plate-common@">=31.0.0" from @udecode/plate-media@31.0.0

npm ERR! node_modules/@udecode/plate-media

npm ERR!   @udecode/plate-media@"*" from the root project

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! For a full report see:

npm ERR! C:\Users\maxen\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-10T17_22_50_842Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\maxen\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-10T17_22_50_842Z-debug-0.log

My package.json :
"dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.18",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-toolbar": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.0.7",
    "@slate-editor/alignment-plugin": "^5.1.0",
    "@udecode/cn": "^29.0.1",
    "@udecode/plate": "^30.9.3",
    "@udecode/plate-alignment": "^30.5.3",
    "@udecode/plate-basic-elements": "^30.7.0",
    "@udecode/plate-basic-marks": "^30.5.3",
    "@udecode/plate-block-quote": "^30.5.3",
    "@udecode/plate-combobox": "^30.5.3",
    "@udecode/plate-comments": "^30.5.3",
    "@udecode/plate-common": "^30.4.5",
    "@udecode/plate-cursor": "^30.5.3",
    "@udecode/plate-dnd": "^30.5.3",
    "@udecode/plate-floating": "^30.5.3",
    "@udecode/plate-heading": "^30.5.3",
    "@udecode/plate-line-height": "^30.5.3",
    "@udecode/plate-mention": "^30.5.3",
    "@udecode/plate-paragraph": "^30.5.3",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "date-fns": "^3.5.0",
    "embla-carousel-react": "^8.0.0",
    "i18next": "^23.10.1",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^2.5.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.344.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^14.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.2",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^2.4.3",
    "slate": "^0.102.0",
    "slate-history": "^0.100.0",
    "slate-hyperscript": "^0.100.0",
    "slate-react": "^0.102.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "tw-colors": "^3.3.1",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^4.2.0"
  }

As mentioned here Could not resolve dependency:
peer @udecode/plate-common@">=31.0.0"
I changed "@udecode/plate-common": "^30.4.5" to "@udecode/plate-common": "^31.3.2" the latest version on npm in my package.json
Then I did npm update --save, npm install, but I get lots of errors because all the other components were installed with udecode/plate-common ^30.4.5 and depend on this version
see errors here and here
npm install

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: portfolio-react@0.0.0

npm WARN Found: @udecode/plate-common@30.4.5

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-common

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-common@"^31.3.2" from the root project

npm WARN   42 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-alignment, ...)

npm WARN 

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer @udecode/plate-common@">=30.4.5 < 31" from @udecode/plate-alignment@30.5.3

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-alignment

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-alignment@"^30.5.3" from the root project

npm WARN   1 more (@udecode/plate)

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: portfolio-react@0.0.0

npm WARN Found: @udecode/plate-common@30.4.5

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-common

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-common@"^31.3.2" from the root project

npm WARN   42 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-alignment, ...)

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer @udecode/plate-common@">=30.4.5 < 31" from @udecode/plate-basic-elements@30.7.0

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-basic-elements

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-basic-elements@"^30.7.0" from the root project

npm WARN   1 more (@udecode/plate)

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: portfolio-react@0.0.0

npm WARN Found: @udecode/plate-common@30.4.5

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-common

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-common@"^31.3.2" from the root project

npm WARN   42 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-alignment, ...)

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer @udecode/plate-common@">=30.4.5 < 31" from @udecode/plate-basic-marks@30.5.3

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-basic-marks

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-basic-marks@"^30.5.3" from the root project

npm WARN   2 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-serializer-md)

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: portfolio-react@0.0.0

npm WARN Found: @udecode/plate-common@30.4.5

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-common

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-common@"^31.3.2" from the root project

npm WARN   42 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-alignment, ...)

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer @udecode/plate-common@">=30.4.5 < 31" from @udecode/plate-block-quote@30.5.3

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-block-quote

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-block-quote@"^30.5.3" from the root project

npm WARN   3 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-basic-elements, @udecode/plate-serializer-md)

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: portfolio-react@0.0.0

npm WARN Found: @udecode/plate-common@30.4.5

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer @udecode/plate-common@">=30.4.5 < 31" from @udecode/plate-cursor@30.5.3

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-cursor

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-cursor@"^30.5.3" from the root project

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: portfolio-react@0.0.0

npm WARN Found: @udecode/plate-common@30.4.5

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-common

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-common@"^31.3.2" from the root project

npm WARN   42 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-alignment, ...)

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer @udecode/plate-common@">=30.4.5 < 31" from @udecode/plate-dnd@30.5.3

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-dnd

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-dnd@"^30.5.3" from the root project

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: portfolio-react@0.0.0

npm WARN Found: @udecode/plate-common@30.4.5

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-common

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-common@"^31.3.2" from the root project

npm WARN   42 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-alignment, ...)

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer @udecode/plate-common@">=30.4.5 < 31" from @udecode/plate-floating@30.5.3

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-floating

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-floating@"^30.5.3" from the root project

npm WARN   2 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-link)

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: portfolio-react@0.0.0

npm WARN Found: @udecode/plate-common@30.4.5

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-common

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-common@"^31.3.2" from the root project

npm WARN   42 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-alignment, ...)

npm WARN 

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer @udecode/plate-common@">=30.4.5 < 31" from @udecode/plate-heading@30.5.3

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-heading

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-heading@"^30.5.3" from the root project

npm WARN   4 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-basic-elements, ...)

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: portfolio-react@0.0.0

npm WARN Found: @udecode/plate-common@30.4.5

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-common

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-common@"^31.3.2" from the root project

npm WARN   42 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-alignment, ...)

npm WARN 

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer @udecode/plate-common@">=30.4.5 < 31" from @udecode/plate-line-height@30.5.3

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-line-height

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-line-height@"^30.5.3" from the root project

npm WARN   1 more (@udecode/plate)

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: portfolio-react@0.0.0

npm WARN Found: @udecode/plate-common@30.4.5

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-common

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-common@"^31.3.2" from the root project

npm WARN   42 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-alignment, ...)

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer @udecode/plate-common@">=30.4.5 < 31" from @udecode/plate-mention@30.5.3

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-mention

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-mention@"^30.5.3" from the root project

npm WARN   1 more (@udecode/plate)

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN While resolving: portfolio-react@0.0.0

npm WARN Found: @udecode/plate-common@30.4.5

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-common

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-common@"^31.3.2" from the root project

npm WARN   42 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-alignment, ...)

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer @udecode/plate-common@">=30.4.5 < 31" from @udecode/plate-paragraph@30.5.3

npm WARN node_modules/@udecode/plate-paragraph

npm WARN   @udecode/plate-paragraph@"^30.5.3" from the root project

npm WARN   4 more (@udecode/plate, @udecode/plate-basic-elements, ...)

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

npm ERR!

npm ERR! While resolving: portfolio-react@0.0.0

npm ERR! Found: @udecode/plate-common@31.3.2

npm ERR! node_modules/@udecode/plate-common

npm ERR!   @udecode/plate-common@"^31.3.2" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer @udecode/plate-common@">=30.4.5 < 31" from @udecode/plate-alignment@30.5.3

npm ERR! node_modules/@udecode/plate-alignment

npm ERR!   @udecode/plate-alignment@"^30.5.3" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

npm ERR!

npm ERR!

npm ERR! For a full report see:

npm ERR! C:\Users\maxen\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-10T17_35_46_285Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\maxen\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-10T17_35_46_285Z-debug-0.log

